# RSA sign in python and verify in JS

Tags: javascript, python, digital-signature, pycrypto

I am using pyCrypto PKCS1_v1_5 signature to sign the message. ([Original code](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html))

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import *
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import base64
import codecs

private_key = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

public_key = """"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDtmBQTFLfaYOsio48B0Sbw4qMn
aXJ7Qk4i1gzI+lgLIOPV0YyUfWMKgl24iJsGN6W5Vk+4GfDE7jKGkti9ZsswaJ/1
Un+zFpXlVCOjEe9CZz3npIEKG8jJL1rwnBc2qPY3YD8jWBhLaPUgchbxUbe1Q2eK
DmlRF7B8BzeNG4aVdQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

message = 'To be signed'
key = RSA.generate(1024)
pub_key = key.publickey().exportKey(public_key) 
priv_key = key.exportKey(private_key)

h = SHA256.new(message)
print '-----------------'
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
signature = signer.sign(h)
print signature
hexlify = codecs.getencoder('hex')
m = hexlify(signature)[0]  #<--- I am sending this hex signature to JS. 
#--------------Code below is to test the verify in python, n it works !   
h = SHA256.new('To be signed')
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key.publickey())
if verifier.verify(h, signature):
   print "The signature is authentic."
else:
   print "The signature is not authentic."
```

for testing to verify in JS, I am using [this](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-rsasign.html) demo sample page. Its written on the page that Signature value should be hexa decimal encoded 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5' signature, so thats why I am converting my signature to hex value in python, but still the signature doesn't match in JS.

I've noticed one strange thing in python code, that is, when ever I generate a signature with **fixed** private key, the signature is not the same. Is this normal ? but in JS it gives me fixed signature every time.

Note: There is a little bug in JS DEMO sample page,go to the source code and change rsa.signString to rsa.sign. And also, change rsa.verifyString to rsa.verify. I've raised [this issue](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/issues/274#issuecomment-313242179) in his Github, he said he'll gona fix it shortly.

Comment: I hope this is just a dummy/throwaway private key you've just posted here :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker you hope right :)

Answer (score 1):

> when ever I generate a signature with fixed private key, the signature is not the same. Is this normal ?

Not normal. With PKCS#1 v1.5 the signature should always be the same with the same private key.

Check the following:

- The SHA256 hash is exactly the same on both ends
- I'm not a Python expert, but it also seems weird that you are calling RSA.generate() when you already have key

Given that your Python code is giving different signature every time, I would concentrate my investigation on that part. If a single byte is different in the input data the produced hash is different - so check with your Python code if the hash is changing with the same input data.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer, suggesting me to check python code and told that its NOT normal to get different signature for fixed private key. I don't know for what reason he deleted the answer, but his observation was right. Actually the way I was getting the key pairs in python is totally wrong. I am generating new key pair every time and exporting it to local variable pub_key & priv_key. Instead I should do something like this;

```
#key = RSA.generate(2048)
#pub_key = RSA.publickey().exportKey(public_key) 
priv_key = RSA.importKey(private_key)
pub_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
```

In this way, I get same signature for this fixed private key, and it really matches the signature of JS code :D ...

Comment: It was my answer. I realized I also had some false observations there regarding your key size so I ended up deleting the answer. I undeleted it and rephrased it a little bit since you found it helpful :)